# What's the impact of large number of file descriptors on Java applications

Tags: java, file-descriptor

We have a web application deployed on Tomcat, which can have over 300k file descriptors, while our limit for single process is 250k. 
The strange thing is: when the server is running, the number goes up (400k) and down (100k). Sometimes, we cannot ssh into the OS when the number is high. However, we didn't find any error related to many open files or socket establish problem. 
Majority of the file descriptors are related to jar files loaded by JVM. My questions are :
1. How does OS (CentOS 7) count the file descriptors for tomcat? I don't think Tomcat keeps those files open while its running.
2. Why is the number not fixed? Instead, there are lots of duplicate jar files. 
3. Is it normal to have so many file descriptors?

Comment: Sockets are files in CentOS, and you will have both inbound sockets from clients and outbound sockets to the back ends. These will come and go like crazy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clears my doubt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operating systems have a limit on the number of files that can be concurrently open by any one process. The default for most distributions is only **1024** files. Each open file also has an associated file-descriptor. Socket connections are treated like files and they use file descriptor, and are therefore subject to the same resource limits.

1. You can verify or change the maximum limit by the command `ulimit`.
2. You can also view value of the MBean Attibutes -
   **MaxFileDescriptorCount** & **OpenFileDescriptorCount** by running the JMX tool- JConsole.
3. When OpenFileDescriptorCount is less than MaxFileDescriptorCount
   your application works fine, otherwise you would get `java.io.IOException: Too many open files` which causes malfunctioning  of your application .
4. Normally for an application the count of the FD(File Descriptor)
   goes up/down to certain level. But it should be within
   **MaxFileDescriptorCount.**

Comment: Thank you Remesh for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of the corresponding native methods of `com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl` (under [`src/jdk.management/unix/native/libmanagement_ext/OperatingSystemImpl.c`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.management/unix/native/libmanagement_ext/OperatingSystemImpl.c#L288)),

- **OpenFileDescriptorCount** is the number of file descriptors under `/proc/self/fds`, and
- **MaxFileDescriptorCount** is simply the value of `RLIMIT_NOFILE`:

> ```
>   RLIMIT_NOFILE
>          This specifies a value one greater than  the  maximum  file  de‐
>          scriptor  number  that  can be opened by this process.  Attempts
>          (open(2), pipe(2), dup(2), etc.)  to exceed this limit yield the
>          error  EMFILE.  (Historically, this limit was named RLIMIT_OFILE
>          on BSD.)
>
>          Since Linux 4.5, this limit also defines the maximum  number  of
>          file  descriptors  that an unprivileged process (one without the
>          CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability) may have "in flight" to other  pro‐
>          cesses,  by being passed across UNIX domain sockets.  This limit
>          applies to the sendmsg(2) system call.  For further details, see
>          unix(7).
> ```